# share ssh session/key with remote user

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, ssh-agent

Assume the following setup:

1. User `bob` is working locally on his workstation `foo`.
2. User `alice` is working locally on her workstation `bar`.
3. User `bob` has ssh access to server `baz:22` via a key stored at `bob@foo:.ssh/id_rsa`.
4. User `alice` has ssh access to `bob`'s workstation `foo:22` but not to server `baz`.

**Is there a way** for `bob` to ssh to `baz` sharing his session (via port forwarding?) or key (via `ssh-agent` forwarding?) such **that `alice` can access `baz` from `bar`** via `foo` (assuming `bob`'s identity on `foo`)**?**

---

**Addendum:**

There are a few more thinks that I should have clarified:

1. `bob` doesn't want `alice` to know his password
2. `bob` doesn't want `alice` to be able to run `rm -rf /home/bob` on `foo` (on `baz` however that would be fine obviously).

As [suggested](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/417245/65290) by [@mukesh-sai-kumar](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/169441/mukesh-sai-kumar),
one could have `alice` login to `foo` (as `bob`?) and `ssh` with the shared key from there.

The best approach I can see so far would be to create a new key-pair for `alice` on `bar`, allow the public key on `foo` and automatically run the `ssh bob@baz` via the `command="ssh [...]"` option in the `authorized_keys` file.

This would allow to setup `ssh baz` on `bar` to actually `ssh bob@foo` using the new key-pair via `alice@bar:.ssh/config` with the forwarding of `bob@foo` logins using this specific key to `bob@baz` via `bob@foo:.ssh/authorized_keys` (authorizing `alice`'s key but restricting `command` to the `ssh baz` call).

This way, the two new constraints would be met and `alice` wouldn't even see anything as this hypothetical interactive session shows:

```
[alice@foo:~] (1) $ hostname
foo    
[alice@foo:~] (2) $ whoami
alice
[alice@foo:~] (3) $ ssh baz
[bob@baz:~] (1) $ hostname
baz    
[bob@baz:~] (2) $ whoami
bob
[bob@baz:~] (3) $ exit
[alice@foo:~] (4) $ hostname
foo    
[alice@foo:~] (5) $ whoami
alice
[alice@foo:~] (6) $
```

**The only remaining problem is that `bob`'s ssh key on `foo` needs to be shared with** `bob`'s session initiated by the `ssh` from **`alice`** (via `ssh-agent`?) **.**

Comment: @JeffSchaller: Thx for the typo fix. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alice can give Bob her public key, and Bob can add a line to his own `.ssh/authorized_keys` file that will allow Alice to start a ssh session (as Bob) on Bob's workstation `foo`. Using the `command=` option, Bob can restrict Alice's key to not grant an interactive shell, but a nested ssh connection to `baz` as Bob, and using a key locally accessible to Bob on `bar`.

`command="ssh -I .ssh/id_rsa bob@baz:22" ssh-rsa AAA...== alice@whatever`

Optionally, you can include further constraint options (`no-port-forwarding`, `from=`, etc. - see `sshd` man page section on AUTHORIZED_KEYS FILE FORMAT).

When Alice runs `ssh bob@bar` and authenticates with her private key, she will be connected through `bar` to a ssh session on `baz`, without having any control over the intermediate session on Bob's workstation.

Note that from the perspective of `baz` (logging, security audit), there is no distinction between this tunneled connection initiated by Alice, and a "normal" connection by Bob from his own workstation. This may be what you asked for, but not what you want.

For making the protected key available to Alice for her session, you can explicitly set the environment variable `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` to be the path that Bob uses for his session (change the `authorized_keys` entry to `command="SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/path/to/bobs/agent_socket ssh bob@baz:22" ssh-rsa AAA...`) To avoid having to update the path when it changes (logoff/login typically), Bob can run a dedicated agent on Alice's behalf with an explicit path specified (`ssh-agent -a ~/.ssh/agent_for_alice` and add only the specific key with `SSH_AUTH_SOCK=~/.ssh/agent_for_alice ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa` and entering the passphrase.

Comment: Thx for the reply. Regarding your last paragraph, that is what I asked for and also what I want. Regarding the rest: As I wrote in the addendum to my question, I already tried that following @mukesh-sai-kumar's answer. The problem is that `bob`'s key requires a password that `alice` must not know. Using `ssh-agent` && `ssh-add` `bob` can load the key using his password and the `ssh baz` using that key without password but I could not figure out how to share that loaded key with `bob`'s session on `foo` under `alices` control from `bar`.

Comment: Bob can prefix the command in `authorized_keys` with an explicit environment variable setting for SSH_AUTH_SOCK to grant Alice access to  his own running agent. Probably better to run a dedicated agent for Alice (using `ssh-agent -a ~/.ssh/agent_for_alice`, and adding only the single key she needs to that agent, by explicitly setting  SSH_AUTH_SOCK). Then the  `authorized_keys` entry can read `command="SSH_AUTH_SOCK=~/.ssh/agent_for_alice ssh bob@baz -p 22" ssh-rsa AAA...`

Comment: Thx for the missing piece. Would you mind editing your answer to include that part to make it more clear for future readers?

Answer (score 1):

## Solution: Nested SSH session.

alice may log into bob's workstation (foo:22) via SSH with the identity of bob, and then log into baz via SSH with bob's identity (and his key, as they both are now accessible to alice).

A command-based representation of this:

```
alice@bar:~$ ssh bob@foo
bob@foo's password:
---snip----
bob@foo:~$ ssh -i /home/bob/.ssh/id_rsa (your-user)@baz
----RSA ID based authentication----
your-user@baz:~$
```

Diagrammatical representation:

```
alice@bar -> Log into foo as user bob -> use bob's stored key to log into baz -> Achieved!
```